# How to join two values in a sublist as tuple pair coordinates in python

Tags: python-2.7

I have the following sublist format:

```
mylist_x_y = [[1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30]]
```

the `[1, 2, 3]` are `X` coordinates and the `[10, 20, 30]` `Y` coordinates.

Now I like them to be the following tuple format:

```
mylist_x_y_new = [(1, 10), (2, 20), (3, 30)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `zip` with the list's elements:

```
mylist_x_y_new = zip(*mylist_x_y)

print(mylist_x_y_new)
```

Output:

```
[(1, 10), (2, 20), (3, 30)]
```